# JButtons in JPanel don't display properly until repainted through resize or action

Tags: java, resize, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

I've had this problem for a while now, searched many forums and sites (including this one), and still did not find an answer to my question.

This is my problem:
I am building a visual calendar. I have a parent panel with multiple panels in it. I repaint the parent panel, and make the 3 overlaying opaque(false). **The paint of the parent panel is not showing until I resize the frame** (or use the buttons that overlay one of the 3, but those are left out in this example because it makes the code longer)

Anyway, here is the code, I simplified it to the problem part:

```
public class Calendar extends JPanel{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1600,150);
    frame.add(new Calendar());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public Calendar(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints cc = new GridBagConstraints();
    cc.weightx = 1;
    cc.weighty = 1;
    cc.gridx = 0;
    cc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    //Initiate Panels
    JPanel yearpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel monthpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel daypanel = new JPanel();

    yearpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    monthpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    daypanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // Set sizes
    int width = (int) this.getPreferredSize().getWidth();
    int height = (int) (this.getPreferredSize().getHeight() / 3);
    yearpanel.setSize(width,height);
    daypanel.setSize(width,height);
    monthpanel.setSize(width,height);

    //make transparent
    yearpanel.setOpaque(false);
    monthpanel.setOpaque(false);
    daypanel.setOpaque(false);
  }        

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/CalendarBackground.jpg");
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
  }
}
```

I have no idea why it does that + I could not find an answer online, only people with the same problem whose question got abandoned :/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would you like to amend your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) - at the moment it doesn't work. You're creating empty `JPanel`s, which are never added to the top-level `JPanel` - i.e `Calendar`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/CalendarBackground.jpg");
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
}
```

1. The `image` should not be loaded in the paint method.  Instead it should be declared as a class attribute and preloaded.
2. The `Toolkit` method is asynchronous, so it is even more important to use the component as the `ImageObserver`.

   `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);`

---

Here is a [working SSCCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981390/418556) that is something like what you seem to be attempting.

[image]

Comment: I was about to write the same suggestions.  Also, instead of using the Toolkit, you can use ImageIO.read(new File(...)).  This returns a BufferedImage that can be used immediately.  You should most definitely not be loading the image in the paint call.

Comment: @Tony  Service with a smile.  :)

Comment: @Tony *"you can use ImageIO.read.."*  Which is exactly what the linked code does.  But to be on the safe side, the `ImagePanel` declares itself as the `ImageObserver`.  That will get the job done even with an image that is asynchronously loaded.  This helps, for example, when using an `ImageIcon` to load an *animated* GIF (which is a bit disconcerting as a BG).

Comment: It's working now! Thank you all, would have never thought of this myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

check the return value of `Graphics.drawImage()`.  I bet it's returning false, which means the image you're painting isn't fully loaded and scaled yet.  Try loading the image somewhere other than your `paintComponent` method, like your `Calendar` constructor.